# SQL - Consolidate and group records from multiple rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, rows

Is there a way to transpose multiple rows and group them to columns?

I have a table that has data from Invoice values from different tables and columns. Now, I want to have them by Invoice numbers.

| InvoiceNumber | Table | Column | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | Column A1 | ABC |
| 123 | A | Column A2 | DEF |
| 123 | A | Column A3 | GHI |
| 123 | B | Column B1 | JKL |
| 123 | B | Column B2 | MNO |
| 234 | A | Column A1 | 1BC |
| 234 | A | Column A2 | 2EF |
| 234 | A | Column A3 | 3HI |

Now, I need to have the details of the Invoice numbers consolidated in the following way.

| InvoiceNumber | ColumnA1 | ColumnA2 | ColumnA3 | ColumnB1 | ColumnB2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL | MNO |
| 234 | 1BC | 2EF | 3HI |  |  |

Would greatly appreciate any help on this. I tried a few options with group by but none of them were effective.

Comment: I belive you are looking for the `pivot` command have you tried it?

Comment: Do you know all possible tables/columns upfront?

Comment: @Miguel, Have never tried Pivot. Will research more on this.

Comment: @PM 77, Yeah. I know all the tables/columns upfront

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a potential solution using pivot.
first create a table

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
   (   INVOICENUMBER VARCHAR2(20), 
       TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(20), 
       COLUMN_VAL VARCHAR2(20), 
       VALUE VARCHAR2(20)
   )
```

lets insert some rows

```
REM INSERTING into TABLE1
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('123','A','Column A1','ABC');
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('123','A','Column A2','DEF');
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('123','A','Column A3','GHI');
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('123','B','Column B1','JKL');
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('123','B','Column B2','MNO');
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('234','A','Column A1','1BC');
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('234','A','Column A2','2EF');
Insert into TABLE1 (INVOICENUMBER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_VAL,VALUE) values ('234','A','Column A3','3HI');
```

now lets query those results with a pivot.

```
WITH cte_mytable AS (
    SELECT
        invoicenumber,
        column_val,
        value
    FROM
        table1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte_mytable PIVOT (
        MAX ( value )
        FOR column_val
        IN ( 'Column A1',
        'Column A2',
        'Column A3',
        'Column B1',
        'Column B2' )
    );
```

[image]